# Using prototype (Design Pattern) to do a simple Frame with Buttons on JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, prototype, design-patterns

Im trying to implement some construction design patterns of the GoF, one of them is "Prototype".
My idea is to create a user interface (A frame with buttons and labels) in wich I can use prototype to clone a button, because my program is a memory game (about Mario Bros :D) all of this on JAVA. I also want to implement my own clone method.

What I think I need to do is to make a button, and when you clone it you only change the name of the button (and maybe the image that the button shows).

First of all I have a class named `Prototype` to clone:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public interface Prototype 
{
    //Method to make a clone
    public Prototype makeClone();

    public JButton getButtonName();
    public void setButtonName(String elDato);

}//end interface Prototype
```

Then, I have my `ConcretePrototypeButton` to implement the interface `Prototype` and use its cloning method.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

    public class ConcretePrototypeButton implements Prototype{
        private String aData;
        static JButton aButton;
        //--------

        public Prototype makeClone(){
            Prototype aClone;
            //---------------
            aClone = new ConcretePrototypeButton();
            aClone.setNombreBoton(this.aData);
            return aClone;
        }//end makeClone


        public String getButtonName()
        {
            return aData;
        }//end getNombreBoton

        public void setButtonName(String aData) {

            Object theName =new String(aData);
            theName=theName.toString();
            //------------

            this.aData=(JButton)theName;
        }//end setButtonName method

    }//end class ConcretePrototypeButton
```

But java shows me a problem in the method `getButtonName` on this line:

```
return aData;
```

Finally I have a third class named `UserInterface` which is my client, but I can not have a `main` 'cause my `main` is in another class that complete my program.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interfaz {

    Prototype aButton;
    Prototype buttonOne;
    Prototype buttonTwo;
    //-------------------

    aButton = new ConcretePrototypeButton();
    aButton.setButtonName("buttonOne");
    //We make a clone
    buttonOne = aButton.makeClone();

    aButton.setButtonName("buttonTwo");
    //We make another clone
    buttontwo = aButton.makeClone();

    //and continue creating buttons to reach 16 buttons.
}//end clase Interfaz
```

But I'm doing something wrong and idk what is it, on this class show me errors on this line:

```
Prototype buttonTwo;
```

And on this:

```
}//end clase Interfaz
```

The idea is to have something like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/te7q.png/
(Tell me if you can not see the image).

I will apreciate a lot if somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance.

ADDITIONAL NOTES:
When i change what the Method returns from JButton to String java sends me another error:
- implements Prototype.getNombreBoton
- The return type is incompatible with: Prototype.getNombreBoton

And if i change that too. how do i can declarate that the target of the that classes is to make objects that are "buttons"?

Comment: Please include a stack trace of the problem.

Comment: You have to change method signature `JButton` to `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

Prototype buttonTwo;

and buttontwo = aButton.makeClone();

both are different it Should be buttonTwo

and for **return aData;**

you are returning String in place of JButton and in this Method

public void setButtonName(String aData) {

```
    String theName;
    //------------
    theName = (String) aData;
    aData = theName;
}
```

the aData here is refering to the Local variable of this method that is of setButtonName(**String aData**) 
also in place of 
aData = theName; 
you should have used this.aData = theName;
this will also give error as we are assigning string to JButton.
So you may want to write your method like this to work

public void setButtonName(String aData) {

```
       Object theName=new String(aData);
       theName=theName.toString();
        //------------
        this.aData=(JButton)theName;

    }
```

This is as per your Code provided here I dont Know you requirement exactly what you wanted to make.
Try this Might it works.

Comment: It looks better, but now java says:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from JButton to 
 String

Comment: I am thinking can you implement Decorator Pattern in this Scenario..?

Answer (score 0):

> But java shows me a problem in the method getButtonName on this line:
>
> return aData;

aData is declared a String

getButtonName returns a JButton

It seems like you have changed your mind about what this method is supposed to do, but not followed it thruough to its conclusion.

Comment: When i change what the Method returns from JButton to String java sends me another error: - implements Prototype.getNombreBoton - The return type is incompatible with: Prototype.getNombreBoton

And if i change that too. how do i can declarate that the target of the that classes is to make objects that are "buttons"?